# Orbit direction in Hamiltonian systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The system
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}\\ \dot{y} \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} y\\ x(1 + 2x^2) \end{pmatrix} =: f(x, y) $$
has the Hamiltonian
$$ H(x, y) = \frac{y^2 - x^2 - x^4}{2} $$
The orbits asymptotically reaching the equilibrium $R = (0,0)$ satisfy
$$ 0 = H(R) = H(x, y) = \frac{y^2 - x^2 - x^4}{2} $$
i.e. we have four distinct orbits and $R$.

To determine which of these orbits converge to $R$ for $t \to +\infty$, is there any better way than evaluating $f$ at sample points?

Answer (score 1):

To the question "is there any better way?" the answer should be "No, in general". But in the few cases where the analytic solution is easy to derive, the direct solving can be a good way :

$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=y \\
\frac{dy}{dt}=x(1+2x^2)
\end{cases}
\quad\to\quad y\frac{dy}{dx}=x(1+2x^2)
\quad\to\quad y^2=x^4+x^2+C$

Given the starting point $(x_0,y_0) \quad\to\quad C=y_0^2-x_0^4-x_0^2$

The equation of the orbit is :
$$y^2=y_0^2+(x^4-x_0^4)+(x^2-x_0^2)$$
$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{y_0^2+(x^4-x_0^4)+(x^2-x_0^2)}$$

[image]

The equation of the particular orbit (red) on which the point $(x=0,y=0)$ lays is :
$$y^2-x^4-x^2=0$$

Asymptotic behavior :

First, consider an orbit in the range $x>0\:,\:y>0 \quad\to\quad 
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=y>0 \\ 
\frac{dy}{dt}=x(1+x^2)>0
\end{cases}
\quad$

Hence $x$ and $y$ are continuously increasing : $x\to\infty$ and $y\to\infty$ when $t\to\infty$ .

$x_0$ and $y_0$ become negligible compared to $x$ and $y$. Thus the orbit  $y^2-y_0^2-(x^4-x_0^4)-(x^2-x_0^2)=0$ tends asymptotically to :
$$y^2-x^4-x^2=0$$
which is the particular orbit pointed out above (drawn on red on the figure).

This was for $x>0\:,\:y>0$. The same method in the other cases proves that the asymptotic behaviour is the same.